# onClick event is not firing in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written the simple ReactJS code. I need to fire an onClick event but it's not working on either button or span element. Here's the code snippet.

```
        function myStatus() {
            return (<div className="col-md-11">
                <label id="sliderLabel" style={{ float: "left" }}>
                <button id="sliderOn" className="sliderOn" onClick={this.activateModal}> Activate </button>
                <span id="sliderOff" className="sliderOff" onClick={this.deactivateModal}> Deactivate  </span>
                </label>
              </div>)
        }
```

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Care to share more code? activateModal and deactivateModal?

Comment: Can you try changing it to `onClick={() => alert('click')}` to see if it is firing?

Comment: There isn't enough code to debug this but are you sure it's not firing the event ? Have you tried logging anything inside `activateModal`/`deactivateModal` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function myStatus() {
  const activateModal = () => console.log("activate the Modal");

  const deactivateModal = () => console.log("deactivate the Modal");

  return (
    <div className="col-md-11">
      <label id="sliderLabel" style={{ float: "left" }}>
        <button id="sliderOn" className="sliderOn" onClick={activateModal}>
          {" "}
          Activate{" "}
        </button>
        <span id="sliderOff" className="sliderOff" onClick={deactivateModal}>
          {" "}
          Deactivate{" "}
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live demo: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-sea-7d7ty?file=/src/App.js)